# UI shifts up after presenting a modal view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm having an issue that just began for my customers where phones that have the top notch seem to shift the UI up behind the status bar after I display a modal and then it's dismissed. Basically I have a UINavigationController that looks fine, the buttons are just below the time and other system indicators, but after displaying a modal view and then it gets dismissed, the buttons in my navigation controller appear behind the time. I have no idea what would cause the shift. Can anyone guide me towards what might cause this as I need to get a fix to my customers quickly.

Thanks!

Comment: I had something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/q/64431327/14351818...

Comment: It may be a bu. Still, any chance you can post more details? Top question - auto layout? Next, safe areas?